# How to groupby multindexed columns with Pandas while keeping the column structure?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiindexed columns I would like to group by level 0 AND 1. Duplicated columns have values I would like to sum. How can I groupby without dropping the other level ? This is what I have tried but it removes one of the level.

Level 0 is dropped.

```
data.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()
Index(['last', 'quoteVolume'], dtype='object')
```

Level 1 is dropped.

```
data.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
Index(['ACA', 'DOT', 'KSM', 'MOVR'], dtype='object')
```

**The columns:**

```
MultiIndex([(       'last',  'DOT'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'DOT'),
            (       'last',  'DOT'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'DOT'),
            (       'last',  'KSM'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'KSM'),
            (       'last',  'KSM'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'KSM'),
            (       'last', 'MOVR'),
            ('quoteVolume', 'MOVR'),
            (       'last', 'MOVR'),
            ('quoteVolume', 'MOVR'),
            (       'last',  'ACA'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'ACA')],
           )
```

How can I do that ?

The expected output is:

```
MultiIndex([(       'last',  'DOT'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'DOT'),
            (       'last',  'KSM'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'KSM'),
            (       'last', 'MOVR'),
            ('quoteVolume', 'MOVR'),
            (       'last',  'ACA'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'ACA')],
           )
```

Comment: please include a sample and expected output.

Comment: I included the expected output, thanks

Comment: Your expected output looks like you almost want to just drop duplicate column indices.,. but your `groupby ` examples seem to indicate you have duplicated columns but also values you want to sum...?

Comment: @JonClements yes, the duplicate columns have values that should be sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this, use the same groupby and set columns later using **[`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html)**

```
out = df.groupby(df.columns,axis=1).sum()
out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(out.columns)
```

---

```
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

`level` [takes a list as parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), just group by `[0, 1]`:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1).sum().sort_index(axis=1, level=1).columns

MultiIndex([(       'last',  'ACA'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'ACA'),
            (       'last',  'DOT'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'DOT'),
            (       'last',  'KSM'),
            ('quoteVolume',  'KSM'),
            (       'last', 'MOVR'),
            ('quoteVolume', 'MOVR')],
           )
```

Comment: For some reason the `.sum()` throws an error `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series`

Comment: Interesting, it works locally for me, assuming you have a data frame with multi Index columns.

Comment: Yes I have dataframe with multi index columns

Comment: Maybe it's a pandas or python version mismatch. Here is the working example: https://akuiper.com/console/G4dxfJ8UtRjL

Comment: There are `nan` in data values I don't know if it is the reason